# How to create a looped animation with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have been sitting on this for a few hours and cannot figure this out. I am trying to create an slideshow (3 slides) that loops endlessly. Each slide is a li inside #slideshow. I have walked through this with a debugger and all variables get set correctly, but I don't understand why the animations dont actually happen. I have this which ends up displaying all images on the page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$slideshow = $('#slideshow');

$slideshowItems = $slideshow.find('li');

$slideshowItems.hide();

nextI = function(x) {       
        if ((x+1) < $slideshowItems.length) {
            return x+1;
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

animation = function(i) {       
    $slideshowItems.eq(i).fadeIn(500).delay(1000).fadeOut(500, animation(nextI(i)));
}

animation(0);
```

If I do:

```
$slideshowItems.eq(0).fadeIn(500).delay(1000).fadeOut(500, 
     $slideshowItems.eq(1).fadeIn(500).delay(1000).fadeOut(500,
         $slideshowItems.eq(2).fadeIn(500).delay(1000).fadeOut(500));
```

This works as expected, but it seems ugly and does not loop.

Any idea why I can't get this to work? I feel it is something with my expectations of how JQuery/ JS modifies the DOM or the sequence that the browser uses to execute animations. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Your code (at the bottom) that works as expected won't actually work. I assume you must actually be including some anonymous functions in there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var $slideshowItems = $('#slideshow').find('li'), 
    i = 0;

(function loop() {

    $slideshowItems.eq( i ).fadeIn(500).delay(1000).fadeOut(500, loop);
    i = ++i % $slideshowItems.length;

})();
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aUDHQ/)**

Comment: Thank you! This is a def a neater implementation! So loop is actually executed after the execution exits the function? Why isn't it executed right after the fadeout(500, loop) is executed? Thanks!

Comment: @mm2887: `loop` is passed as the second argument to `fadeOut`, which means it will be executed after the `fadeOut` is complete. So both lines of the `loop` function are executed immediately, the animation (with the delay) runs taking 2000ms, then when the `fadeOut` is complete, it invokes `loop`, starting the process over. Remember that functions are objects that can be passed around like any other object. So you can pass a function as an argument to another function, and have that other function invoke it for you at a later time.

Comment: @RightSaidFred: That makes sense, thanks. I am still trying to understand why my original implementation didn't work. Is it because I was a passing a call to animation() and that was being executed before the fade() actually executed resulting in an endless loop where fade actually never executes?

Comment: @mm2887: Yes, you were making the recursive `animation()` call immediately instead of passing the function. That's why I took the incrementing of `i` outside instead of passing `i` as an argument. Because I didn't need to send an argument to the `animation()` function, I could just pass the function itself directly. The alternate approach is to wrap the invocation of `animation(nextI(i))` in an anonymous function like @TiC did. This way you're passing a function object that invokes the `animation` function at a later time.

Comment: @RightSaidFred thanks a lot! That really helps my understanding.

Comment: @RightSaidFred--There is something I don't understand about your implementation. Since `loop` is the second argument to `fadeOut` and `i` is incremented outside of `loop`, when `loop` is called a second time, `i` will not have changed. It will be 0 twice, right?

Answer (score 1):

You should specify a callback method but your "animation(nextI(i))" returns nothing, so nothing remains to do after the fade out is complete.

Something like this I think will work:

```
var animation = function(i) {       
   $slideshowItems.eq(i).fadeIn(500).delay(1000).fadeOut(500, function (){
      animation(nextI(i));
   });
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It seems my mistake was that I assumed that passing animation(nextI(i)) would actually enter the function and execute the call. I still don't understand why it doesn't? Why does it have to be wrapped in an anonymous function?

Answer (score -1):

I would try setting that as a function and then using setInterval:

```
setInterval(function(){
    $slideshowItems.eq(0).fadeIn(500).delay(1000).fadeOut(500, function() {
       $slideshowItems.eq(1).fadeIn(500).delay(1000).fadeOut(500, function() {
           $slideshowItems.eq(2).fadeIn(500).delay(1000).fadeOut(500);
       });
    });
}, 6000); // 6000 milliseconds before loops
```

Comment: I took the code he said worked, and put a setInterval around it, how is that incorrect?  You can adjust the amount of milliseconds to match the length of the animation...

Comment: Because the code he said works doesn't work. It requires anonymous functions to run as a callback. But even then, the timing would be off. As you said, it could be adjusted. The proper interval would be 6000ms. And even then you may find issues because in some browsers these sorts of timers are known to be terribly inaccurate, so if it ran long enough, it could start looking very out of sync. Or if you switch browser tabs, the timers do funny things in some browsers. [Let this run for a while](http://jsfiddle.net/aUDHQ/1/) to see. Also, the initial animation will be delayed.

Comment: I understand that a recursive function would have worked better, unfortunately my answer was rushed because of holiday fun, hopefully i'll have a chance to correct/update it later. Thank you for letting me know about inaccuracies between browsers, I was unaware of that.

Comment: I updated it for you to add the needed anonymous functions (needs peer review), and removed the -1.